# What is meant by Switching charge ( under Gate charge characteristics) in the given MOSFET datasheet?

Tags: mosfet, power, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, semiconductors

What is switching charge in this [MOSFET](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_IPP075N15N3_G_DS_v02_06_en-3164923.pdf) datasheet?

[image]

The switching actually takes place during Miller region. Hence I belive Qgd should be called as switching charge. But looks like the remianing gate charge ( after deducting Qgs and Qgd from total gate charge) is tagged as switching charge.

[PS: Below snaps are taken from a different document/ [application note.](https://www.vishay.com/docs/73217/an608a.pdf)]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *What is meant by Switching charge ( under Gate charge characteristics)
> in the given MOSFET datasheet?*

I think this diagram on page 7 of the data sheet will help: -

[image]

In other words, they call switching charge the charge between the gate reaching the threshold voltage and the end of the Miller plateau.